# Storage of data to file - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, csv, multidimensional-array

I am attempting to make an app that has a simple data storage, retrieval and update mechanic. There will be about 200 entries, each with a unique identification integer, a known and fixed string and finally an unknown second integer which will require to be updated by the user.

I have attempted to create and save this data to storage as a multidimentional array, SQLite database, a CSV (using http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/) however no matter what I try even if it is just straight up copy and pasting code from tutorials and other stackoverflow questions the code will not compile usually with some error relating to there being no exception, or it is incomplete (such as an example of how to store, but never retrieve or an SQLite example that can only select all).

I am coding with Android Studio and have no issue getting the rest of my program running on my handset via ADB, however as soon as I try and implement the data storage and retrieval, it does not work.

Can someone please tell me the absolute SIMPLEST way to store, retrieve and update my data set.

Comment: Your question is labelled **c# android**. What language do you actually use?

Comment: sorry, got confused. fix'd

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with files are more complicated. Usage of `Sqlite` is recommended. Just create a table and store your 2 integers and String .The unique `integer` can be made as `primary key` then the updation and retrieval will be more easier and flexible. Creating csv and maintaining it will be headache comparing to this

Comment: Definitely use SQLite

Comment: Can anyone vouch for the tutorial at http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

If someone can confirm that this looks solid, I will attempt that again and get more specific with my issues regarding its implementation.

Comment: Try to use sqliteOpenHelper thats the standard way to use database,. Lot of tutorials are out there

Comment: Can you please provide a link to one that you know for a fact is complete and operational?

Comment: Try http://10keyes.blogspot.in/2012/08/android-implementing-sqliteopenhelper.html and http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: That first one is far far too brief and is missing large amounts of functionality and all usability code. The second is one way too complicated and gets lost on its focus of its overall programming.

I just want something that says "this is how you create a bare bones database with X columns, Y entries, how to select all, select one, delete all, delete one, drop tables, update etc." and there is just nothing out there that actually does that.